# How to get all discord dms id using python request

Tags: python, python-requests

i wanna make a code that everytime my account receive a dm it gets notificate in a wweebhook.

getting all dms and then keep verifying if there is a new dm, and if it is, send the webhook to my discord warn server, please can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not that what you are trying to do is against the discord [TOS](https://discord.com/terms) and I have nothing to do with what you are trying that violates the terms of service.

```
pip install discord.py discord-webhook
```

```py
import discord
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

# Discord webhook URL for sending notifications
WEBHOOK_URL = 'your_webhook_url_here'

# Create a Discord client
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name} ({client.user.id})')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if the message is a DM and not sent by the bot itself
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) and not message.author.bot:
        # Create a webhook object
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL, content=f'New DM from {message.author}: {message.content}')
        
        # Send the webhook notification
        response = webhook.execute()
        print(f'Sent webhook notification: {response}')

# Run the Discord client
client.run('your_bot_token_here')
```

Comment: i wanna use requests not discord.py, since i need to use it in a real discord account